# Modular Java Application

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, decoupling

I am trying to separate my projects into two different jars. First one will be the 'core' jar which will have all business logic. Second one is for command prompt version which will use core. Following is the project structure with content and code snippet.

**CoreApp Project Structure**

```
CoreApp
  - src
    - com.myapp.service
      - CoreService.java
  - lib
    - thirdPartyX.jar
  - coreFile.txt
```

**CmdLine Project Structure**

```
CmdLineApp
  - src
    - com.myapp.main
      - MainClass.java
  - lib
    - thirdPartyY.jar
    - coreApp.jar
  - input.txt
```

**MainClass.java**

```
public class MainClass {
  pulic static void main(String[] args) {
    File inputFile = new File("input.txt"); //OK
    ...
    coreService.doSomething(); //ERROR
  }
}
```

**CoreService.java**

```
public class CoreService {
  public void doSomething() {
    File coreFile = new File("coreFile.txt"); //NOT OK 
    ...
  }
}
```

And I am facing couple of issues:

1. cmdLineApp doesn't have thirdPartyX.jar even I have coreApp.jar in it. ( For now as workaround instead of coreApp.jar in lib directory I am adding CoreApp project in the build path of CmdLineApp in STS)
2. When running main() method application can access/find input.txt but not coreFile.txt. (I don't wan to put coreFile.txt) in CmdLineApp project as it is strictly used in core only).

So my question is how I can make files being picked up without having to write/hard coded the absolute path. And How I can organized jar along with third party jars in this kind of project structure.

The reason for having separate core is I will be developing web based version too in which I will make use of core service method from the controller. So both cmd line and web based will use same core code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. cmdLineApp doesn't have thirdPartyX.jar even I have coreApp.jar in it. ( For now as workaround instead of coreApp.jar in lib directory I am adding CoreApp project in the build path of CmdLineApp in STS)

Most "Pro" applications deal with this by instantiating their own `ClassLoader` with the corresponding CLASSPATH settings. Usually this is done using `URLClassLoader`. They would store the additional `.jar` archives in a `lib/` directory. You can write the code that creates the `URLClassLoader` in a way that it picks up whatever `.jar` is in that `lib/` directory so you would not need to touch that code if you add, remove or rename `.jar` files.

If the `.jar` files are plugins, you could even go as far as having a second `ClassLoader` in connection with a `java.nio.file.WatchService` in order to detect changes to the `.jar` archives at runtime.

> 2. When running main() method application can access/find input.txt but not coreFile.txt. (I don't wan to put coreFile.txt) in CmdLineApp project as it is strictly used in core only).

If you only ever need to read that file, place that file as a resource inside the .jar file and use `getClass().getResourceAsStream()` or `getClass().getResource()` to access the file. Note, it no longer will be a `File` but an `InputStream` or a `URL`, but if you read only, this should not matter.

If you need to write to this file, you would go for the previous approach, store the data in a temp file which you could create using `File.createTempFile()` and remember the path using `java.util.prefs.Preferences`.

Comment: Code to load *.jar and files using URLClassLoader should be in CoreApp or CmdLine project?

Comment: That depends. If your CmdLine loads your CoreApp and CoreApp would load the reset, then there would be such code in both.

Comment: -I am not sure what you mean by 'reset' but CmdLine will just use the service as shown in MainClass.java

Comment: Sorry that was a spelling mistake, it should have been "rest".